# QOpenGLWidget cannot use more than one sampler2D

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, binding

I've created a very basic shader:

```
static const char *frag_showImage =
"#version 150\n"
"uniform sampler2D textureSampler;\n"
"in mediump vec2 texc;\n"
"out highp vec4 fragColor;\n"
"void main() {\n"
"   fragColor = texture2D(textureSampler, texc.st);\n"
"}\n";
```

And it works as expected, now a bit more complex one:

```
"#version 150\n"
"uniform sampler2D textureSampler;\n"
"uniform sampler2D maskSampler;\n"
"in mediump vec2 texc;\n"
"out highp vec4 fragColor;\n"
"void main() {\n"
"   fragColor = texture2D(textureSampler, texc.st);\n"
"   fragColor.x = texture2D(maskSampler, texc.st).x;\n"
"   fragColor.y =0;\n"
"}\n";
```

It doesn't work but it has no warnings neither errors:

in both cases I bind the first texture as:

```
QOpenGLFunctions *f =this->context()->functions();
f->glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBaseTexture->bind();
m_program->setUniformValue("textureSampler", 0);
```

and the second texture is binded as:

```
f->glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);    
glMaskTexture->bind();
m_program->setUniformValue("maskSampler", 1);
```

Notice that if I bind glMaskTexture for the first shader it works ok so the problem is not on that QOpenGlTexture.

Any idea? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is `glBaseTexture` a QOpenGLTexture?

Comment: yes, both glBaseTexture and glMaskTexture are QOpenGLTexture pointers

Comment: The code pasted looks correct, perhaps the problem is in some code you didn't paste. I would suggest to run this into Apitrace or some other tracer and check the GL status before your draw calls...

Comment: Thank you I'll do that, to be honest I'm driving nuts just by removing 
    fragColor.x = texture2D(maskSampler, texc.st).x; it works fine, it seems that there is something wrong about uniform sampler2D maskSampler

Answer (score 0):

Goblins: renaming maskSampler to other name it works ok, I have no idea about why this is happening since "maskSampler" is not used in any other part of the code.